# Get offset of current buffer in vim (in particular, via python scripting)

Tags: python, offset, vim

i want to get the offset of

1. the current cursor position
2. the current selection range

in vim, beginning from the start of the file. I do this in python, so hints how to do it with vim's python scripting would be very helpful.

I have used vim.current.. before for doing scripting, but it uses lines and columns rather than a general offset.

Would i have to calculate the amount of all preceding line lengths + the current row, or is there a simpler method ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your vim is compiled with the [`+byte_offset`](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/various.html#+byte_offset) option, then in a Python script after the usual `import vim`, you can use, e.g.:

```
vim.eval('line2byte(line("."))+col(".")')
```

to get the byte offset from start of file of the cursor position, and similarly for other marks. More generally, if you have a line/column pair this (assuming `+byte_offset` is how your vim was compiled with) is the way to get a byte offset (there's also a `byte2line` function to go the other way).

While the vim module does make a lot of functionality available directly to Python scripts in vim, I've found that `vim.eval` and `vim.command` are often the handiest (and sometimes the only;-) way to get in just as deep as needed;-). Oh, and I always try to have a vim compiled with +justabouteverything whenever I can;-).

Comment: Thank you, that is very very helpful !!
I suspected that there must be such a way if the actual API doesn't support it :-)

Comment: or directly: `:echo eval(line2byte(line("."))+col("."))`

Comment: With Vim 8.2 or Neovim 0.4.4 I have a more accurate result with `:echo(eval(line2byte(line("."))+col(".")-1)`

Answer (score 15):

You may also want to look at the `statusline` setting.  This will add the bye offset to the statusline:

```
set statusline+=%o
```

See `:h statusline`

Just be careful because the default statusline is blank, and by appending the %o to it, you loose all the defaults.

Comment: To display the status line when you open have one window: `set laststatus=2`